# SyslogNG message format

Tags: syslog-ng

I am reading through some syslog-ng documentation, and in the section about filter functions, it says that the `program()` filter matches...

> ...messages by using a regular expression against the program name field of log messages.

The documentation also includes similar definitions for other filter functions.

How is the program name field set in a log message? Is there some documentation somewhere which summarises this for the various fields? I couldn't find it in the documentation I have ("The syslog-ng Administrator Guide").

Answer (score 2):

The program name field is set by the application sending the log message. If you want to override this for some reason, you can use the program_override() option in the syslog-ng source definition. I am not sure which syslog-ng versions support this option, it is surely available in 3.0 and later.

HTH

Robert

Answer (score 0):

From `man 3 syslog`:

```
   (...)
   #include <syslog.h>

   void openlog(const char *ident, int option, int facility);
   void syslog(int priority, const char *format, ...);
   void closelog(void);

   openlog()  opens a connection to the system logger for a program.  
   The string pointed to by ident is prepended to every message, 
   and is typically set to the program name.
```

Program name is set inside code of the program using the system logging facility.